# Display images in selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm displaying div ids onclick and it's working fine, those divs have images inside them i want to display the image of the selected div as well and keep it in the original div, but when i try to do it only one image gets displayed and it gets removed from it's div, i want all of the selected div images to be toggled like their id, here is the code:

```js
  let ids = [];
 $(".select").on("click", function () {
     ids.indexOf(this.id) === -1 ? ids.push(this.id) : ids.splice(ids.indexOf(this.id), 1);
     $(this).toggleClass('selected');
     $('#selected-id').html(ids.join(", "));
     $('.selected-imgs').html($(this).children('img'));      
 });
```

```css
.select {
display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select" id="1">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/886465/pexels-photo-886465.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<div class="select" id="2">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/872957/pexels-photo-872957.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<div class="select" id="3">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/669615/pexels-photo-669615.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<p id="selected-id"></p>
<div class="selected-imgs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code is Updated:**
You can something like below:

```js
let ids = [];
  $(".select").on("click", function () {
  if (ids.indexOf(this.id) >= 0) { // logic to remove
   $(".selected-imgs").children("img").eq(ids.indexOf(this.id)).remove();
   ids.splice(ids.indexOf(this.id), 1);
   $('#selected-id').html(ids.join(", "));
   return;
  }
  // logic to add
  ids.push(this.id)
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $('#selected-id').html(ids.join(", "));
  $(this).children('img').clone().appendTo('.selected-imgs'); //clone and append the image
  
});
```

```css
.select {
display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select" id="1">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/886465/pexels-photo-886465.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<div class="select" id="2">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/872957/pexels-photo-872957.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<div class="select" id="3">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/669615/pexels-photo-669615.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<p id="selected-id"></p>
<div class="selected-imgs"></div>
```

Comment: this way it adds the image more than once, i want to add it once and on the second click to remove it like with it's id

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the selected div's html to the target div. Here is how you can do that:

```js
let ids = [];
 $(".select").on("click", function () {
      var src = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
      var i = 0;
     ids.indexOf(this.id) === -1 ? ids.push(this.id) : ids.splice(ids.indexOf(this.id), 1);
     $(this).toggleClass('selected');
     $('#selected-id').html(ids.join(", "));
      $('.selected-imgs img').each(function (){
          if($(this).attr('src') === src)
          {
            $(this).remove();
            i += 1;
          }
      })
      if(i === 0)
      {
          $('.selected-imgs').append($(this).html()); 
      }
          
 });
```

```css
.select {
display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select" id="1">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/886465/pexels-photo-886465.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<div class="select" id="2">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/872957/pexels-photo-872957.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<div class="select" id="3">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/669615/pexels-photo-669615.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" height="100">
</div>

<p id="selected-id"></p>
<div class="selected-imgs"></div>
```

Comment: this way it adds the image more than once, i want to add it once and on the second click to remove it like with it's id